# How can I make bodies that do not stick to the wall in Bullet Physics?

Tags: physics, movement, bullet-physics, billiards

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Physics engine recommendation which can simulate pool game correctly?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/12003/physics-engine-recommendation-which-can-simulate-pool-game-correctly)

I made a Billiards scene with Bullet Physics, but I've got a problem. When the ball is slowing down near a wall, it sticks to that wall and slides along it. It normally bounces, but at those low speeds it sticks instead of bouncing.

What's wrong? What should I set to make sure the ball always bounces when it hits the wall? I used barebone `btRigidBody`, with no parameters set.

Comment: Could You post Your .blend file?

Comment: @user712092 Oh I solved this problem already. See here: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/12003/physics-engine-recommendation-which-can-simulate-pool-game-correctly Anyway, thanks for care!